# git search diff in specific commits

Tags: git

In GIT, I want to find the commits where some text has changed, but I only want to search in specific commits. I tried:

```
git log -S<my-search-text> <commit-hash1> <commit-hash2> <commit-hash3>
```

The commits I want to search in are not a range. Does anyone know how to do this, or have an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You could try grepping `git log`'s output with the hashes you want:

```
git log -S<my-search-text> |grep -E '<commit-hash1>|<commit-hash2>|<commit-hash3>'
```

Note that you have to use a regexp, hence the `-E` (you could also use egrep), and that the pipes must be escaped, so you either have to use them inside quotation marks, or as `\|`. An alternative syntax is:

```
git log -S <my-search-text> |grep <commit-hash1> -e <commit-hash2> -e <commit-hash3>
```

---

Depending on your use of this functionality, you could be interested in doing it with `git diff` and `grep`:

```
git diff <commit-hash1> <commit-hash2> <commit-hash3> | grep <my-search-text>
```

This will show you every change that occurred in the commit range, that contains the search text.